# unique hash for the browser id - how can I find out if the user is using the exact same browser

Tags: security, angularjs, browser

I'm working on implementing a security (tfa) feature in the server side of a webapp. I want to store a hash that contains **unique** information about the client browser, computer,session settings etc. so that if he logs from another browser/computer we could notify him and ask for permission (or something similiar) and prevent using the app from two session at once.

what data can I obtain from the browser that could help me achieve that. or any other Ideas about implementing this.

(using angular, but I can implement with vanilla js)

Answer (score 0):

Read about device/browser fingerprinting (you can search both in Google, and both in Gooogle Scholar for academic papers):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint

See this site for example (it takes your fingerprint):
http://noc.to/